# Measure actual size of object in image given pixel dimension and distance from camera

Tags: computer-vision, pixel

I'm working with computer vision application, and I need to know the actual size (height) of object in image given the pixel height and the distance from camera.

I have this setup:

[image: setup_1]

the black circle in left is the object with known height of 2cm, having 18cm distance from the camera (color red). Using the Y-component of bounding rectangle I got the  pixel height of object which is 50px.

On the second setup I placed the object closer to camera:

[image]

and I got 50px in height. I know that the relationship between the distance and height is inversley proportional. But given this information, i cannot connect these numbers to acquire the actual height of unknown object to be placed like this:

[image]

The distance from the camera is not fixed, I need to know the actual size given the distance and pixel height.

any idea ??? please help me .. Thank you

BTW 
can i use this???

say:
 y = actual height, x = pixel height, z = distance

the relationship would be :     y = xz/k

is it right ?

Comment: Naive answer: 2cm * 95/80, since distanse has not changed. Gonna elaborate on this later though

Comment: Thanks for answering. hmm but the distance is not fixed ..

Comment: In case you have shown last two pictures do have 13 cm distance, so I've used Tales law

Comment: Make sure you measure the correct distance between the camera and the object. I don't know the exact optics, but you probably have to measure to some plane inside the lens. Possibly the point of convergence or the sensor or the shutter. Your figure seems to indicate that you measure to the tip of the lens, which might mess up the equations.

Comment: Figure 2 in this article explains what I mean. If you know the focal length, the distance to the object, and the pixel height of the image, you can calculate this using basic trigonometry.
http://www.rags-int-inc.com/phototechstuff/lens101/#L_TERM

Comment: By the way, there's another QA site about mathematics that's probably a better place to ask this question. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @HåkenLid Thanks for the idea, but i think i don't need much about the focal length since i'm relying with the object's pixels in image, although its inaccurate but i can start from it and do calibration. So i think it's really about the algorithm and relationship with the variable

Comment: but I'm still confused hmmm